# .DLL not in file path after building project

Tags: dll, directory

Im making a simple .DLL using .NET 6.0 class library but when I build, My .DLL is never made or does not appear inside my directory. Im also not getting any errors inside Virtual Studio.

I cant seem to find any solution.